# How to get pucrchase order of only particular one product at button click?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

I am adding a smart button at the product level. That button will be visible on every product from view. When I am clicking on that button, I want to open purchase order for that particular product.

This is my method on button click.

```
    def view_purchase_order(self):
        action = self.env["ir.actions.actions"]._for_xml_id("purchase.purchase_rfq")
        print(self, "SELFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF")
        tree_view = [(self.env.ref('purchase.purchase_order_tree').id, 'tree')]
        action['views'] = tree_view
        action['res_id'] = self.id
        return action
```

I have inherited `product.template` in my custom view.

I have already set the `ID` of that product in `action['res_id']` but still I am getting all purchase order record.

Can anyone help me with how to get purchase order of that particular product only?

Answer (score 0):

`self` represent recordset. So you can get it with id.

For example, `self.id`

Comment: Yeah Bhavesh, Thank You. But by only setting id to red_id I am not getting record of that particular product. Let me update my question.

Comment: I think that I also need to set context to get record of that particular product.

Comment: set `domain` to get records

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too

```
def view_purchase_order(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'name': 'Purchase Orders',
            'view_mode': 'tree, form',
            'res_model': 'purchase.order',
            'domain': [('order_line.product_id', '=', self.id)],
            'context': "{'create': False}"
        }
```

Comment: will I get purchase order of only product with id 23 by setting domain?

Comment: yes, can you please try this and let me know

Comment: I am getting blank tree view with 0 records

Comment: I think in self.id there is product.template id instead of product.product..pass self.product_id.id

Comment: Error: 'product.template' object has no attribute 'product_id'
can you please edit it in your code so I can get clearly that what you are telling me to change.

Answer (score 0):

From your last comment `Error` look like you are on the `template` so to get the `product` access you need to set the **domain** like this way.
You can take the **Adam Solution**, where try to change this line,

```
'domain': [('order_line.product_id', '=', self.product_variant_id.id)],
```